# Pyplot not plotting subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am creating a subfigure with pyplot and plotting everything in it's axis. I am trying to work with two separate figures at the same time `fig` and `cor`. What I'm doing is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure(1)
cor=plt.figure(2)
ax=plt.subplot(111)
bx=plt.subplot(211)

ax.plot(dates_obs,obs,label='L1')

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
lgd = ax.legend(handles, labels, loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.,1.))
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0*0.5, box.y0*1.2, box.width * 0.75, box.height*1.05])
ax.grid('on')

fig.savefig('test.png', bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,))
```

However, the plot comes out blank.

I tried to define `bx` as a subfigure of `cor` and `ax` as a subfigure of `fig`, hence the `bx=plt.subplot(211)`, but I guess that's not what the argument `2` means.

If I work from `plt.`, without defining `fig` (for example, `plt.plot(dates_obs,obs)`), it sort of works (except for the handles definitions and etc.) but I can't do that because I have to work with two figures at the same time.

Am I missing something basic here?
Thank you very much,

Comment: Your code seems to be working for me (except for the aspect ratio of the figure or of the axes) ... is your figure blank or do you see the axes but no data?

Comment: Completely blank. My matplotlib version is 0.99.1.1.

Comment: @JulienSprink Sorry, there is an error in my question. I'm fixing it right now.

Comment: Now, I can reproduce your error ... see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code, you created `fig` and `cor`, then you created `ax` and `bx`. By default, these will be plotted on the last figure you created, `cor`. Then, you save `fig` (which is empty since the plots are on `cor`).

Use the following for the axes definition to make sure that your axes are created on the right figure:

```
fig=plt.figure(1)
...
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
bx=fig.add_subplot(211)
...
fig.savefig('test.png', bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,))
```

You can do something similar for `cor`